# Opencart theme installation issue

Tags: php, opencart

cart 2.2.0 I have downloaded free theme from the website but still I am unable to install that theme because in the `system>setting>theme`
in theme tag that theme is not available after extracting 
`/catalog/view/theme`

Answer (score 3):

To change a theme on Opencart 2.2.0.0, follow  below setting:

1. Login to admin panel.
2. Go to  Extension > Themes > Edit
3. Select your **theme** for **Theme Directory** option
4. Click on save to activate your new theme.